# What is difference between RS_KERNEL and __attribute__((kernel)) in RenderScript?

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm reading sample of code of using RenderScript (https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/be17bffb7b1dcc69467a52bcb94bec4306c3ca4b/HdrViewfinder/Application/src/main/rs/hdr_merge.rs#L27) and documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute#writing-an-rs-kernel). There are 2 different ways of defining kernel:

```
uchar4 RS_KERNEL invert
```

and

```
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) mergeHdrFrames
```

Which one should I use? Which one is correct? Does it depends on SDK API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after detailed reading I can see that `RS_KERNEL` is a macro to `__attribute__((kernel))`